# Stencil: How to fix "It's recommended to set the "main/module" property to index.js/.mjs"

Tags: package.json, stenciljs

I have stenciljs component project called `@platform/ux`. The UX package is published to a private NPM feed. Via that feed I am able to install the UX package and import it into my other projects with `import '@platform/ux'`. At the moment it works fine when having the following settings in my package.json

```
"main": "dist/platform-ux.js",
"module": "dist/platform-ux.mjs",
"es2015": "dist/esm/platform-ux.mjs",
"es2017": "dist/esm/platform-ux.mjs",
"types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
"collection": "dist/collection/collection-manifest.json",
"collection:main": "dist/collection/index.js",
"unpkg": "dist/platform-ux/platform-ux.js",
```

With these settings I get the following warning in the console when using the UX package in my projects.

```
[platform-ux] Deprecated script, please remove: <script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');</script>
To improve performance it is recommended to set the differential scripts in the head as follows:
<script type="module" src="platform-ux/platform-ux.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="platform-ux/platform-ux.js"></script>
```

When I build my UX project I get the following warnings:

```
[ WARN  ]  Package Json: package.json:12:5
           package.json "main" property is set to "dist/platform-ux.js". It's recommended to set the "main" property to:
           ./dist/index.js

     L11:  "version": "1.0.17",
     L12:  "main": "dist/platform-ux.js",
     L13:  "module": "dist/platform-ux.mjs",

[ WARN  ]  Package Json: package.json:13:5
           package.json "module" property is set to "dist/platform-ux.mjs". It's recommended to set the "module" property
           to: ./dist/index.mjs

     L12:  "main": "dist/platform-ux.js",
     L13:  "module": "dist/platform-ux.mjs",
     L14:  "es2015": "dist/esm/platform-ux.mjs"
```

I think the warning in my console and warning in my build logs might be related so I though I would change it to the recommended file names (see below configuration). When I change the file names in the package.json to the following, the warnings disappear. But once the package is published the `import '@platform/ux'` in my other projects don't work anymore. I get no console errors or anything.

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"module": "dist/index.mjs",
"es2015": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
"es2017": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
"types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
"collection": "dist/collection/collection-manifest.json",
"collection:main": "dist/collection/index.js",
"unpkg": "dist/platform-ux/platform-ux.js",
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Sadly following the recommended settings just breaks my setup. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter/blob/master/package.json#L5-L12 and do you have that `src/index.ts` file (https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter/blob/master/src/index.ts)?

Comment: Yes to both. As you can see in my question, my package.json matches the one you've linked (except the project name of course).